# What is the inverse of a matrix with the following structure?

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have come across a $N \times N$ square matrix of the following structure

\begin{bmatrix}
m_1 & m_2 & m_3 & \ldots & m_{N-1} & m_N \\
1 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}

where the $m_i \neq 0$s are real constants. Is there an analytic expression for the inverse of this matrix?

Comment: You have to assume $m_N\neq 0$ for it to be invertible.

Comment: At least one of the $m_{i}$s must be different from zero so that the matrix has and inverse.

Comment: All the $m_i$s are non-zero. I have edited the question.

Comment: This is a [Hessenberg matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the matrix is invertible, its inverse can be expressed as follows. Define
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
m_1 & m_2 & m_3 &.....& m_{N-1} & m_N \\
1 & -1 & 0 &.....& 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 &.....& 0 & 0 \\
. & . & . &.....& . & . \\
. & . & . &.....& . & . \\
. & . & . &.....& . & . \\
0 & 0 & 0 &.....& 1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We can write $A = M - I + xy^T$, where $I$ is an identity matrix,
$$
M = \pmatrix{0\\1&0\\&\ddots&\ddots\\&&1&0}, \quad x = (1,0\dots,0)^T, \quad  y = (m_1 + 1,m_2,\dots,m_N).
$$
Using the [Sherman Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), we have
$$
A^{-1} = (M - I)^{-1} - \frac{(M - I)^{-1}xy^T(M - I)^{-1}}{y^T(M - I)^{-1}x}.
$$
$(M-I)^{-1}$ is easy to compute: since $M$ is nilpotent of order $N$, we have
$$
(M - I)^{-1} = -I - M - \cdots - M^{N-1} = 
\pmatrix{-1&0\\ \vdots & \ddots \\
-1&\cdots &-1}.
$$